# Association sequelize 3 tables, many to many

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 4 tables

```
- client
- project
- user
- userProject
```

One Project belongs to client and it needs to have client foreign key client_id.

UserProject has project_id and user_id foreign keys, belongs to project and user.

One user owns the clients of his projects.

- How can I list the clients of one user?

Comment: Please provide the way you tried and troubles you got.

Comment: I have no idea how. I thought you would say me a way to do this.
I understant sequelize, and I cannot have problemes with simple associations of 2 tables.

Answer (score 8):

I'm wondering you could use [eager loading](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#nested-eager-loading) feature from [sequalize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/):

```
Client.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Project,
    include: [{
      model: User,
      where: {
        id: <UserId>
      },
      required: false
    }]
  }]
}).then(function(clients) {
  /* ... */
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This creates a many-to-many relation between `user` and `project`. Between `user` and `client` you therefor have a many-to-many-to-one relation. This is not supported by sequelize. I would have created an instance method on the `User` model like this:

```
User = sequelize.define('user', {
  // ... definition of user ...
},{
  instanceMethods: {
    getClients: function()  { 
      return this.getProjects().then(function (projects) {
        var id_map = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
          id_map[projects[i].clientId] = 1;
        }
        return Client.findAll({
          where: { id: [Object.keys(id_map)] }
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

and then call this function when you have a user instance like this, to get the clients:

```
user.getClients().then(function (clients) {
  console.log(clients);
});
```